# Kafka Streams left join behaviour is wrong without foreign key selector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

In the following stream in the second and third left join a foreign key selector must be specified although both the `durchfuehrungen` and `befunde` as well as `durchfuehrungAufgabeAggregate` have the same key type, namely `durchfuehrung.id`. Otherwise, ie. when omitting `{ it.durchfuehrungEvent.durchfuehrung.id }` the joins won't be calculated.
I didn't find any explanation either in the API or elsewhere, but the behaviour is very disturbing as I wouldn't expect to have to provide a foreign key selector when I don't need one as all there topics have the same key type.

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun durchfuehrungAggregator() =
        Function { durchfuehrungen: KTable<String, DurchfuehrungEvent> ->
            Function { projekte: KTable<String, ProjektEvent> ->
                Function { projektStatus: KTable<String, ProjektStatusEvent> ->
                    Function { befunde: KTable<String, DurchfuehrungBefundAggregat> ->
                        Function { durchfuehrungAufgabeAggregate: KTable<String, DurchfuehrungAufgabeAggregat> ->
                            Function { projektAufgabeFaelligkeiten: KTable<String, ProjektAufgabeFaelligkeitAggregat> ->
                                durchfuehrungen
                                    .join(
                                        projekte,
                                        { it.durchfuehrung.projektId },
                                        { durchfuehrungEvent, projektEvent -> DurchfuehrungAggregat.from(durchfuehrungEvent, projektEvent) }
                                    )
                                    .leftJoin(
                                        projektStatus,
                                        { it.durchfuehrungEvent.durchfuehrung.projektId },
                                        { durchfuehrungAggregat, projektStatusEvent -> durchfuehrungAggregat + projektStatusEvent }
                                    )
                                    .leftJoin(
                                        befunde,
                                        { it.durchfuehrungEvent.durchfuehrung.id },
                                        { durchfuehrungAggregat, durchfuehrungBefundAggregat -> durchfuehrungAggregat + durchfuehrungBefundAggregat }
                                    )
                                    .leftJoin(
                                        durchfuehrungAufgabeAggregate,
                                        { it.durchfuehrungEvent.durchfuehrung.id },
                                        { durchfuehrungAggregat, durchfuehrungAufgabeAggregat -> durchfuehrungAggregat + durchfuehrungAufgabeAggregat }
                                    )
                                    .leftJoin(
                                        projektAufgabeFaelligkeiten,
                                        { it.durchfuehrungEvent.durchfuehrung.projektId },
                                        { durchfuehrungAggregat, projektAufgabeFaelligkeitAggregat -> durchfuehrungAggregat + projektAufgabeFaelligkeitAggregat },
                                        Materialized.`as`(DurchfuehrungAggregatStore.NAME)
                                    )
                                    .toStream()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```